# How to fetch some data from one table, in different html divs

Tags: php, html

i am having some problems and i was hoping you will help me.
This is the website i'm testing on: http://rblueberry.epizy.com/

So what i want to do is: for all this boxes on website to fetch from database, but in that order, how can i do that?

Do i need to make more tables for those boxes(articles) or i can do it other way?

Sorry if im not explained very well, i really don't know how to explain it better.

Comment: sorry can't understand your question

Comment: The thing is, i want to fetch data from table articles. I can do it for first article, but i can't do it for other articles next to that first article.

Comment: What I understand so far is that. The boxes (articles) on the mention website are coming from database table called articles. What you want I don't understand?\

Comment: Not all articles are coming from the database, just first one.
I want all of them to come from database. But when i try to do that, all the articles are from one row in the table.

For example i have two rows in table articles, i want to fetch them all, not just one row.

Comment: Maybe this will be easier to understand:
How to fetch one(different) row for each article? But to be in the style of the website. Like:

`Article 1 ----- Article 2 ----- Article 3(New line after article 3)
  Article 4 ----- Article 5 ----- Article 6`

Comment: So your Table Article has 2 rows and each row has different Article but you are able to fetch only 1 article not all. right?

Comment: show some code then i can figure out whats wrong with your code

Comment: Here mate:
https://pastebin.com/KJqZMNmy

Comment: Take variable like $html = ' '; before while loop and assign your html to this variable like $html = $html . YOUR html (concatenate your html)

Comment: "So your Table Article has 2 rows and each row has different Article but you are able to fetch only 1 article not all. right? "
No mate, i can fetch it, but i want to fetch 1 row for first article, 1 row for second article, 1 row for third article. They need to be different rows of course.

Comment: Did you try my this comment
"Take variable like $html = ' '; before while loop and assign your html to this variable like $html = $html . YOUR html (concatenate your html) "

Comment: I don't get it.
I take all html code or just the part of the article? And then what next?

Comment: this question is missing some code. Questions without code (and which need code, like this one seems to) can be closed as off-topic. N.B. Linking to code in external sites doesn't count as these can change or disappear over time, making the question useless for future readers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic . I suggest you edit your question to include all the relevant details within the actual question text itself. Thanks.